# Camanjs clear canvas when init Caman()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, camanjs

I apply Caman Filter to a canvas with existing image data. But when I create Caman object to use later, it emply my canvas.

`var ca = Caman('#myCanvas');`

I'm try to do exactly with [Caman Guide](http://camanjs.com/guides) , like this:

```
Caman('#myCanvas',function(){
   this.render();
});
```

But the same problem, canvas is clear! Why I cannot load canvas to Caman then modify, although [documentation](http://camanjs.com/guides/#BasicUsage) says can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to grab a reference to the Caman object with: `var ca = Caman("#myCanvas");`

First, draw something on the original canvas:

```
// make a drawing on the original canvas

var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(20,20,60,40);
```

Then tell Caman to use #myCanvas as both the source and destination for any filters:

```
// modify the original drawing from #myCanvas and put it back on #myCanvas

Caman("#myCanvas",function(){
    this.brightness(50).render();
});
```

*About your cleared canvas:*

Since Caman uses .getImageData, be sure your image is hosted on the same site as the web page you're serving otherwise a CORS security violation will cause your canvas to be blank.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("original");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// make a drawing on the original canvas
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 40);

// modify the original drawing 
Caman("#original", function () {
    this.brightness(75).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/4.0.0/caman.full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="original" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: Oh, Image I got from camera (canvas drawn image from video). I found another solution: create temp canvas, manipulation on this, when render complete, I copy temp to #myCanvas. It's done. But I'll check that problem soon as soon. Now, just run for deadline. Thank you so much!

Comment: the fiddle is not working. The blue thing is gone when you initialize Caman.

Comment: @speedingeer. The Fiddle works fine for me in Chrome, FF & IE! As expected, the blue rect turns a less bright blue. But "just in case" I've moved my demo from JSFiddle to StackSnip and verified it's working. :-) Anyway, I hope you still found the answer useful because the entire code was in the narrative part of the answer.

Comment: @markE
I've upvoted your answer. It's a CamanJs bug https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/issues/188.
Your code works fine if it's not retina screen. Hope guys will fix it.