# CamanJS initialize on canvas with image (RETINA BUG)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, camanjs

EDITED:
It turned out it's a retina bug. Not replicable on other screens.

Referring [Camanjs clear canvas when init Caman()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774086/camanjs-clear-canvas-when-init-caman) and posted there http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/R4kJM/ CamanJS should accept the canvas with data s argument. Ale documentation seemed to confirmed this fact. But somehow the fiddle is not working. The blue thing disappears once CamanJS initialize.

The code again:
http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/R4kJM/

HTML:

```
<canvas id="original" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("original");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// make a drawing on the original canvas
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 40);

// modify the original drawing 
Caman("#original", function () {
   this.brightness(75).render();
});
```

Comment: "The blue thing" doesn't disappear, it just gets brighter because you put `this.brightness(75).render();`. Try removing that line of code.

Comment: I did. It's the same. (using chrome)

Comment: https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/issues/188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the bug in CamanJS. The issue still and work around described here.

https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/issues/188

Comment: You might mention that the bug affects Retina displays only so future viewers aren't confused by your fiddle links which work fine in non-retina displays. ;-)